# How to run two processes sametime on qemu

Tags: c, qemu

I want to communicate between two processes A and B using message queue.

- Process B 
      openeds a message queue in READ-ONLY, which waits for the message.
- Process A sends the 
      data to process B, Now I ran process B on q emu, which is waiting for
  message.

The question is:
to send 
     message I need to run process A, how can I run process A when process B is already running 
     on `QEMU`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: run process B in background using `&`. Example `./helloworld &`

Comment: Thanks jeyaram, it is working